# solr 7.4.0 security.json authentication

Tags: solr

I am not so familiar with solr. I tried following what was stated in the solr 7.4.0 manual concerning authentication and granting roles using the security.json file below:

```
{
"authentication":{
  "blockUnknown": true,
  "class":"solr.BasicAuthPlugin",
  "credentials":{"solr":"IV0EHq1OnNrj6gvRCwvFwTrZ1+z1oBbnQdiVC3otuq0=Ndd7LKvVBAaZIF0QAVi1ekCfAJXr1GGfLtRUXhgrF8c="}
},
"authorization":{
  "class":"solr.RuleBasedAuthorizationPlugin",
  "permissions":[{"name":"security-edit","role":"admin"}],
  "user-role":{"solr":"admin"}
}}
```

When I tried accessing the admin UI ( localhost:8983/solr/#/ ) I was prompted for a user-name and password. I typed in "solr" as user-name and "SolrRocks" as password but the login popup keeps reappearing. when cancelled it says "Error 401 Bad credentials". Please may I know the right way to perform authentication using the security.json file as stated in the manual?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a space in your password hash (after the equals sign)

```
Correct:
    "credentials":{"solr":"IV0EHq1OnNrj6gvRCwvFwTrZ1+z1oBbnQdiVC3otuq0= Ndd7LKvVBAaZIF0QAVi1ekCfAJXr1GGfLtRUXhgrF8c="}

Incorrect:
    "credentials":{"solr":"IV0EHq1OnNrj6gvRCwvFwTrZ1+z1oBbnQdiVC3otuq0=Ndd7LKvVBAaZIF0QAVi1ekCfAJXr1GGfLtRUXhgrF8c="}
```

Comment: On the manual there was a line break after that equals sign which made it difficult figuring out there is actually a space there. Anyway, I can't really figure out if your answer will work because I have actually switched to Elasticsearch after discovering Elasticsearch was easier to setup because it had fewer configurations to set compared to Solr.